# PHPMailer in PHP: Buttons don´t display properly

Tags: php, html, forms, button, phpmailer

So I´ve set up PHPMailer and after testing a little and receiving my first basic-html mails (Everything was completely fine!) I moved over to send some html which is more sophisticated - and I chose to send a `<form>` with a `<input type="submit">`-element (I did not use `<button type="button">` out of support reasons). Anyways, while the HTML I´m sending displays as I intended when opening it in FireFox, sending the html in the PHPMailer-Body to my Microsoft Outlook leaves the button look like blank text, and when clicking on it nothing happens, so the `<form>` somehow does not redirect to the page I specified in its action-attribute (I´m using post as method). What I´m expecting is that when clicking on the properly-looking button my default webbrowser will be opened and it will send the data from the form via POST to the page set in the action-attribute of the form.
I think both problems (no-button-display, no-redirect) have to do with the same origin, but I don´t know what could cause this to happen. Is there no way of sending forms in an e-mail?
Thanks for all answers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy: Don't send forms in email. They really don't work well. Support is extremely patchy and unreliable, especially in Outlook. Send them to a web page with a form on instead.